# Git list out stashes specifically from one branch

Tags: git, git-stash, git-reflog, gitlist

I have 2 branches: Section9 and s9feature. On the branch s9feature I made `stash`, then I `checkout` on Section9 branch and want to see the list of stashes specifically from s9feature. I know that I can run `git stash list` or `git reflog stash` but I need to list out stashes specifically from s9feature

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stashes are based on *commits*, not branches.  However, the default "title" of a stash—which is actually just its commit message, as each stash is just a commit that's not on *any* branch<sup>1</sup>—has the form `WIP on branch`.  So, you can run `git stash list`, and then use a *filter* on its output to extract any line containing the branch name.  For instance:

```
git stash list | grep s9feat
```

(remember that `grep` searches for any substring, so as long as `s9feat` is long enough to distinguish the interesting stashes from the uninteresting ones, that's all we need here).

If you've changed the titles of the stashes, of course, this won't work.  Since branch names are meaningless and irrelevant to Git, and only appear in the *human-oriented message* part, you'd need something considerably more complicated to find the interesting stashes—unless, that is, you already put the interesting part into these changed titles.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, each stash is at least *two* commits.  Stashes made with particular options add a *third* commit to hold untracked files.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the default "title" of a stash has the form WIP on branch

The problem is: it does not display the *full* name of the branch it was created on. Not before Git 2.36 (Q2 2022)

"[`git checkout -b`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/11da0a558063a94498932ed3d73dbabf1bda6dd0/Documentation/git-checkout.txt#L148)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt--bltnew-branchgt))</sup> branch/with/multi/level/name && [`git stash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/11da0a558063a94498932ed3d73dbabf1bda6dd0/Documentation/git-stash.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash))</sup> **only recorded the last level component of the branch name**, which has been corrected with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022).

See [commit ceaf037](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ceaf037f617eb774bb8a451c1779dd9b8b12152a) (24 Jan 2022) by [Glen Choo (`chooglen`)](https://github.com/chooglen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 11da0a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11da0a558063a94498932ed3d73dbabf1bda6dd0), 06 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`stash`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ceaf037f617eb774bb8a451c1779dd9b8b12152a): strip "refs/heads/" with `skip_prefix`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Kraymer</sup>
> <sup>Reported-by: Daniel Hahler</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Glen Choo</sup>

> When generating a message for a stash, "[`git stash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ceaf037f617eb774bb8a451c1779dd9b8b12152a/Documentation/git-stash.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash))</sup> only records the part of the branch name to the right of the last /".
> e.g.
> if HEAD is at "foo/bar/baz", "`git stash`" generates a message prefixed with `WIP on baz:` instead of `WIP on foo/bar/baz`:.
>
> Fix this by using `skip_prefix()` to skip "`refs/heads/`" instead of looking for the last instance of "`/`".